# Emacs: Adding custom code block delimiter?

Tags: emacs, syntax-highlighting, delimiter, parentheses

I using emacs to write some [ejs](http://embeddedjs.com) files. I have set

```
(show-paren-mode t)
```

in my .emacs for highlighting parentheses. The ejs code looks like:

```
<ul>
    <% for(var i=0; i<supplies.length; i++) {%>
        <li><%= supplies[i] %></li>
    <% } %>
</ul>
```

It seems that this mode doesn't work fine when editing ejs using html-mode. For example, a left '<' in '<%' matches the '}' on the right instead of matching a '%>'.

So my question is can I add '<%' as a code block delimiter to make show-paren-mode work fine in ejs files?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: ewwww.  All the ugliness of ERB.  Now on client-side!  ;)

Answer (score 2):

Have you really fully thought out how this this bracket highlighting might work?

You have have a naked starting delimiter "{" starting delimiter in between
"<%" and "%>".

This is equivalent to:

```
( { )
```

Does `show-paren-mode` highlight such code properly?

Editing mixed major-mode files (JS in HTMl), (Ruby in HTML), is hard in Emacs.

You can use this snippet to remove "<" and ">" as matching delimiters, which
alleviates your problem a little.

```
(eval-after-load "sgml-mode" '(progn
                                (modify-syntax-entry ?< "'" sgml-mode-syntax-table)
                                (modify-syntax-entry ?> "'" sgml-mode-syntax-table)))
```

But you need a multi-major-mode library to really get it to work, but I doubt
anyone's put in the work to make "EJS" work.

Comment: I have tried mmm-mode too, everything is fine except the bracket highlighting. show-paren-mode doesn't work in this.